# C# reading an Array from IQueryCollection

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dynamic

Working in a C# Asp.netcore project, I'm trying to read an array from an IQueryCollection in a GET request. The IQueryCollection is in Request.Query.

I need to read the query without a model. When the front end json hits the back end, its no longer JSON which is fine, I just need to read whatever the front end passed. In this example its a int array but it could be anything.

Models don't scale very well for queries. To return a model on a get, they work brilliantly but for a query that can be as complex or simple as it needs to be I can't commit to models. Would be really usefull if I could extract the query to an anonamous object.

Json passed from the front end:

```
var params = {
   items: [1, 4, 5],
   startDate: new Date(),
   endDate: new Date()
}
```

C# Request.QueryString

```
{?items%5B%5D=1&items%5B%5D=4&items%5B%5D=5&startDate=Fri%20Oct%2015%202021%2022%3A30%3A57%20GMT%2B1000%20(Australian%20Eastern%20Standard%20Time)&endDate=Fri%20Oct%2015%202021%2022%3A30%3A57%20GMT%2B1000%20(Australian%20Eastern%20Standard%20Time)}
```

I've tried:

```
// Gives me a null
var value = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.QueryString.Value).Get("items");

// Gives me an empty object {}
var value = Request.Query["items"];
```

Hope this is enough information.

Comment: Thanks for the suggetion, I'm sure that works fine but I'm trying to access the query values without a model.

Comment: Then you must use a JSON (de)serializer to get the value of the "itemPks" property.

Comment: I've gone that way too, since I'm passing the JSON object into the get request, its turned into a get query, the ugly string in the post and is no longer considered JSON in the back end. If I did a JSON.stringify in the front end it might solve this issue but I will most certainly be plagued by this issue again as I go along into the project.

Comment: The json string gets url-encoded, you have to decode it before parsing.

Comment: Did you try Googling this? Even with a site:stackoverflow.com at the end?

Comment: Also... You can specify a partial model to retrieve just the values that you're interested in.

Comment: I've spend hours on this(googling it and trying suggestoins). The problem I have with models is that they don't scale very well for queries. To return a model on a get they work brilliantly but for a query that can be as complex or simple as it needs to be I can't commit to models. Would be really usefull if I could extract the query to an anonamous object.

Comment: C# Request.QueryString doesnt even contain `itemPks`. It's completely different value than the json

Comment: yes good point @Alexander, the example was a bit disjointed sorry. I've updated the post with the actual code without cleaning up the QueryString. Thanks for picking that up.

Comment: Thanks for the advise @CodeCaster, I've updated the question to be more complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query string format is undefined for arrays. Some web frameworks use `?foo[]=1&foo[]=2`, others use `?foo=1&foo=2`, again others `?foo[0]=1&foo[1]=2`.

You'll have to use the same parsing serverside as you serialize it clientside.  This works for your `[]` syntax:

```
var queryString = "?items%5B%5D=1&items%5B%5D=4&items%5B%5D=5&date=2021-10-15";

var parsed = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);

foreach (var key in parsed.AllKeys)
{
    if (key.EndsWith("[]"))
    {
        var values = string.Join(", ", parsed.GetValues(key));
        Console.WriteLine($"{key}: array: {values}.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{key}: scalar: {parsed[key]}.");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
items[]: array: 1, 4, 5.
date: scalar: 2021-10-15.
```

But instead of parsing the query string yourself, let the framework do that. You say you don't find models scalable; I find that hand-crafting code doesn't scale well. A model like this would just work, granted you fix your date serializer on the JS side:

```
public class RequestModel
{
    public int[] Items { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just on the note of models, so every time you add a query to an endpoint, you add it to a single model. Would that mean that if I had a API endpoint that returns a collection and that query could search on 40 properties, the model would have 40 properties?